# Visual Studio 2013 interprets my file as a form file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I create simple cs file with one class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bed
{
    public class TimeoutWebClient : WebClient
    {
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
            w.Timeout = 30 * 1000;
            return w;
        }
    }
}
```

suddenly my visual studio has interpreted it as a form class.. where did I go wrong?

[image: VS screen]

These are the versions I use:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
>   Version 12.0.21005.1 REL
>   Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.5.50938

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how it happened but this is how I fix it:

- right-click on the project and choose 'unload'
- right-click on the project and choose 'Edit'
- find in the file 'TimeoutWebClient'

I expect you to find something like this:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="TimeoutWebClient.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="TimeoutWebClient.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>TimeoutWebClient.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <!-- other files go here -->
```

Remove the `SubType` tag. If you also want to undo any dependencies remove the `<DependentUpon>` tag as well.

Save your project file, right-click it and choose 'Reload'.
Verify if you achieved what you need.

Comment: solution works, but it is temporary, VS after restart add SubType again.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio interpreted it as a `WebClient` as you extend this base class in your code. The same happens when you e.g. extend `Form` class - VS will interpret it as form and will display it as a form.
Still it doesn't interfere with your development. As you see on the print screen you access code by right clicking and selecting "View Code" option.

Answer (score 0):

rene described solution, some more information:

In project file only:

```
<Compile Include="TimeoutWebClient.cs">
  <SubType>Component</SubType>
</Compile>
```

You need to remove SubType tag to fix